# How to accept SSL Certificate in selenium chrome webdriver

Tags: ssl-certificate

I am not able to accept SSL Certificate in selenium chrome driver while accessing application url

first i need to access url, then i have to accept ssl certificate.. But while accessing url itself, ssl will get display and am not able to accept the certifictae since url is not opened yet

Can somebody help on this

Comment: have you seen https://www.guru99.com/ssl-certificate-error-handling-selenium.html ?

Comment: yes.. That didn't work.                                                            
DesiredCapabilities handlSSLErr = DesiredCapabilities.chrome ()       
handlSSLErr.setCapability (CapabilityType.ACCEPT_SSL_CERTS, true)
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver (handlSSLErr);

Comment: Can somebody help on this!

Answer (score -1):

Below solution will definatly work for you.

```
WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup();
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.addArguments("--ignore-certificate-errors");
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", 
System.getProperty("user.dir")+"/Drivers/chromedriver.exe");
driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
driver.get(applicationURL);
driver.manage().window().maximize();
```